# How does Keycloak encode group membership in id tokens

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, keycloak

I have configured a user `my_user` who belongs to `my_group` in Keycloak 4.8.3. I have then obtained an id token for it with grant type Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC). When I inspect the issued id token with a tool such as [`jwt.io`](https://jwt.io/) I can see that the user's id and name are included as JWT clains `sub` and `preferred_username` respectively.

But where does group membership show up inside the JWT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create mapper. In Keycloak Admin Console go to Clients, choose your client, tab "Mappers", click Create in the header of the grid. In Mapper type combo choose Group Membership and fill other data (Name, Token Claim Name).

Comment: This worked for me when trying out Concourse with OIDC from Keycloak. (Along with "Token claim name"="groups" and "Add to ID token" = on)